# Remove HTML element from parsed HTML document on a condition

Tags: php, html, string, html-parsing, substring

I've parsed a HTML document using Simple PHP HTML DOM Parser. In the parsed document there's a ul-tag with some li-tags in it. One of these li-tags contains one of those dreaded "Add This" buttons which I want to remove.

To make this worse, the list item has no class or id, and it is not always in the same position in the list. So there is no easy way (correct me if I'm wrong) to remove it with the parser.

What I want to do is to search for the string 'addthis.com' in all li-elements and remove any element that contains that string.

```
<ul>
    <li>Foobar</li>
    <li>addthis.com</li><!-- How do I remove this? -->
    <li>Foobar</li>
</ul>
```

FYI: This is purley a hobby project in my quest to learn PHP and not a case of content theft for profit.

All suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couldn't find a method to remove nodes explicitly, but can remove with setting outertext to empty.

```
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load(file_get_contents("test.html"), false, false); // preserve formatting

foreach($html->find('ul li') as $element) {
  if (count($element->find('a.addthis_button')) > 0) {
    $element->outertext="";
  }
}

echo $html;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But it appears that my example code was over simplified. Here is a (beautified) paste of the html. Prepare to do backflips. http://pastebin.com/M4W49Zku

Comment: Updated to work with your full HTML. I detect the <li> tag to remove by testing presence of an <a> with class = addthis_button.

Comment: Works great! I would +1 if I had the rep to do it. Anyone that can feel free +1 this!

Answer (score 1):

Well what you can do is use jQuery after the parsing. Something like this:

```
$('li').each(function(i) {
    if($(this).html() == "addthis.com"){
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: Why not just `$('li:contains("addthis.com")').remove()`?

Comment: Not everything has a reason, but I agree that your solution is less lines :)

Comment: @Adam What I want to do is to search for the string 'addthis.com' in all li-elements and remove any element that contains that string. THAT is the question...

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I intend to pass this to a mobile app so I'd rather do this on the server side.

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses [DOMDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) class and [domnode.removechild](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domnode.removechild.php#90292) method:

```php
$str="<ul><li>Foobar</li><li>addthis.com</li><li>Foobar</li></ul>";
$remove='addthis.com';
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($str);
$elements = $doc->getElementsByTagName('li');
$domElemsToRemove = array();
foreach ($elements as $element) {
  $pos = strpos($element->textContent, $remove); // or similar $element->nodeValue
  if ($pos !== false) {
    $domElemsToRemove[] = $element;
  }
}
foreach( $domElemsToRemove as $domElement ){
  $domElement->parentNode->removeChild($domElement);
}
$str = $doc->saveHTML(); // <ul><li>Foobar</li><li>Foobar</li></ul>
```